# How can I create a RangeValidator for Int64? BigInt? Long?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, validation

So I'm trying to use the RangeValidator to ensure the minimum and maximum value of Int64 is validated. But, the only or closest option that I seem to have is Double.

```
Dim Range As New RangeValidator
Range.ControlToValidate = "..."
Range.Type = ValidationDataType.Double
Range.MinValue = Int64.MinValue.ToString
Range.MaxValue = Int64.MaxValue.ToString
```

I don't want to use a custom validator. I suppose I could use some crazy regular expression.. but just trying to understand why I can't do this.

For example, the max value of Int64 is:

```
9223372036854775807
```

But this validates:

```
9223372036854775808
9223372036854775810
9223372036854775899
```

It will not validate if I jump up a larger number:

```
9223372036854799999
```

I'm assuming it's due to some conversion taking place for a Double.

I do see there's a LongValidator in System.Configuration, but I'm trying to avoid creating a CustomValidator type if at all possible and it's a different validate type, as in not intended for use like RangeValidator.

All of this is more so for learning purposes than anything else. I'm aware I can jump through other hoops but hoping to get better clarity.

Tagged C# as well. Ignore my vb.net example.. not really important based on the question. Will convert any code either way.

Comment: maybe the same question as [using-asp-net-rangevalidator-for-int64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537971/using-asp-net-rangevalidator-for-int64) ?

Comment: @Sam Saw that one, only I don't think they actually ran into the problem that I did. They ended up using a regex and a range, but it's still a problem with the Double type.

Comment: :) fair enough, I'm afraid I'm not savvy enough as to why it's validating but I'd assume you're on the right track with the double type ..

Comment: @Sam It's driving me crazy. I just wish Microsoft would add more data types in the validators. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a plausible answer on a [forum by PLBlum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1012368.aspx?RangeValidator+MaximumValue+Double+MaxValue+ToString+fails)

> I want to clarify something. RangeValidator does not use a
>   regularexpression to validate a double. It uses a regular expression
>   to extract the digits and decimal character out of the string. It then
>   converts the result into an actual number using the javascript
>   parseFloat() function. If that function cannot convert, the
>   RangeValidator knows the value was not acceptable to javascript.
>
> I suspect that the problem is that the value you are assigning to
>   MaximumValue is too large for javascript's floating point. I think
>   both .net's Double and javascript are 80bit floating point but its
>   possible they are slightly different at the min and max range. In any
>   case, I recommend changing your code like this:
>
> - Use a CompareValidator, Operator=DataTypeCheck, Type=Double. It will report an illegal value due to the format or its too big for an 80 bit
>     number.
> - Use another CompareValidator, Operator=GreaterThanEqual, Type=Double, ValueToCompare= your minimum double. This will report an
>     error if anything is below the minimum. The max was handled in the
>     other validator.

Maybe that explains why it is validating incorrectly.

Comment: Interesting approach, and I very much so appreciate you helping me research. I think the problem still stands, because I don't want to allow decimal places, and your suggested workaround would do exactly that. I can always use a custom validator... I'm just stumped as to why there isn't another way. Thanks again @Sam.

Comment: Know what... this sparks a thought. Gonna try something.

Comment: Nope didn't work. Disabled the client-side validation and it still failed, so back to the double issue.

Comment: At this point I'd just go with a custom solution really, in my opinion even if there's a standardised way it's obviously not very well documented, loosing more time researching it over actually writing it yourself and move on.. :) we are programmers after all, right? :D

Comment: I went with a regex. I ended up with a migraine after constructing it, but it works. All of this was more for research/learning anyway, and I do appreciate your help and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone else wants to chime in, realistically there's one way I found to do this, and that's with a custom validator. There's a function in System.configuration that allows the ability to check if a value is a valid "Long". The problem is, if you want client-side validation it seems the only valid option is to use a regex. Otherwise, the number is just too big and JavaScript parses it as a float, as Sam mentioned.

So, I ended up using a regex as to gain client-side and server-side validation.